# Preserve trailing zeroes using NumberFormatter in PHP

Tags: php, intl, numberformatter

I'm working on upgrading a legacy system from PEAR's i18nv2 class to PHP's built-in INTL library. When I specify a pattern like `#,##0.##` and run `NumberFormatter::format()` on a number like `12345.1000` I get `12,345.1` shouldn't trailing zeroes be preserved? Is there a good way to add trailing zeroes after the fact taking into consideration that in many locales, a decimal is represented by a comma instead of the decimal character?

Explained with code:

```
$n = new NumberFormatter('en_CA', NumberFormatter::PATTERN_DECIMAL, '#,##0.##');
echo $n->format(12345.10000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classDecimalFormatSymbols.html

```
Symbol   Meaning
  0      a digit
  #      a digit, zero shows as absent
```

So:

```
$n = new NumberFormatter('en_CA', NumberFormatter::PATTERN_DECIMAL, '#,##0.00');
echo $n->format(12345.10000);
```

Yields:

```
12,345.10
```